# Is there a limit of covariates that finalfit can handle for a generalized linear model?

Tags: r

I'm handling a dataset for a case-control study, with a binary outcome variable, using the `finalfit` package.
When using the `finalfit` function (which incorporates the `glm` function for the logistic regression, I get trouble when incorporating more than 11 explanatory binary variables.

Here's an example

```
library(dplyr)
library(finalfit)

#An example of the dataset:
o <- c(0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0) #would be the outcome variable
exp1 <- c(0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1) 
exp2 <- c(1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1) 
exp3 <- c(0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1) #would be the explanatory variable and so on....

data<-as.dataframe(o,exp1,exp2,exp3) #and the other variables

explanatory = c("exp1", "exp2", "exp2")
dependent = 'o'
data %>%
  finalfit(dependent, explanatory)
```

When running the code with less than 11 explanatory variables, it works just fine, but crashes with more than 11 explanatory variables.
The error is **Tibble columns must have compatible sizes. * Size 5: Existing data. * Size 4: Column at position 5. ℹ Only values of size one are recycled.**

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no limit. It behaves exactly like `glm`. The problem is likely due to the underlying model. Check it is converging with:

```
data %>%
  glmmulti(dependent, explanatory)
```